# How can I increase the size of the VirtualBox screen?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm trying to run Arch Linux within VirtualBox 5.1.28 where the host OS is Windows 10. The problem is that the display size is too small, even when I maximize the window size. Check out this screenshot to see what I mean:

[image: Arch Linux in VirtualBox 5.1.28]

I googled this problem but every potential solution I've come across said to install Guest Additions, but as you can see from the screenshot above, I do not have the option to install Guest Additions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

0. Install Guest Additions and use a windowing system such as X11.
1. Open a terminal in your guest Arch system.
2. Run `VBoxClient --vmsvga`.
3. Enjoy your auto-sized VirtualBox Arch system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a bit of a pain, but what you are looking for is:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "your_vm_name" setvideomodehint Xres Yres ColorDepth
```

example:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "Win7Pro_32-bit" setvideomodehint 1464 834 32
```

or with an Archlinux guest:

```
VBoxManage controlvm arch_1_64 setvideomodehint 1366 864 32
```

For windows guest, the resize is immediate as long as WindowsGuestAdditions are installed, for Linux guests, issue the command, and restart the VM.

For the boot framebuffer resolution within the Archlinux guest itself, see [**Setting the framebuffer resolution**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution)

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem.

Just adjust VirtualBox-General's Display "`Maximum screen size`" and "`Scale Factor`";

and adjust guest machine-General's Display "`Scale Factor`";

also choose guest machine-Settings's Display "`Resolution`".

I have just used "`VirtualBox`" to install "`Debian`" on "`Mac`", so just use this for example.

Please do the same functional operation on your Host Windows, VM VirtualBox and guest "`Arch Linux`".

When a new virtual machine witness on mac, first step is to adjust virtual

machine's scale factor and maximum screen size, second step is to adjust

guest's scale factor, third step is to adjust guest's resolution, fourth

step is to restart host machine(e.g: macOS/Windows).

Just as `Virtual Box` manually installed `Debian` on `Mac` for example:

My host machine `macOS` Retina display is `13.3 inch` (`2560*1600`);

My virtual machine VirtualBox`6.1.32` Max scale factor is `300%`;

And, VirtualBox default interface is `400*300`with scale factor `100%`;

Now,

1.VM scale factor and max screen size:

click `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

move your mouse to top menu, found out `VirtualBox`logo, select

"`Preference`", then enter "`VirtualBox - General`", click `Display`,

Choose "`Maximum screen size`" to "`Hint`" with Width "`1280`" and

Height "`800`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`", then click

"`OK`".

2.Guest scale factor:

When you enter `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

found out your guest machine name button, as mine is "`linux_debian_11`",

you will see "`Power Off`" under the name of your guest machine.

Please found out your guest machine "`Menu Box Button`", that is at the right

of your guest machine name, right click your "`Menu Box`" or single click your

"`Guest Machine Box`", choose "`Settings`", then you will enter your guest

machines's "`General`", mine is "`linux_debian_11 - General`", then click

"`Display`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`"(the same as `Scale Factor`

on virtual machine's "`General`").

3.Guest Resolution:

My guest machine is "`Debian`". So, just use "`Debian`" for an example here.

click my guest machine "`Debian`"'s "Settings", then found out "`Display`",

and, also, choose "`Resolution`" to "`1280*800(16:10)`".

No matter your Debian version is "`8`", or even "`11`", the upstairs settings

is OK.

Are you Ok? Said, Lei Jun.

4.Reboot Host Machine:

Now, it's your time show!

Please restart my Mac.

Finally, "`Guest Resolution`" *  "`Scale Factor`" == "`Host Display size`".

"`1280*800`" * "`200%`" == "`2560*1600`";

VirtualBox Default interface is 400*300 with "`100%`", it's too small, so

"`Scale Factor`" should be from "`100%`" to VBox's max "`300%`". Also, has:

"`2560*1600`" * "`100%`" == "`2560*1600`"; (But VirtualBox Enter Wins will

too small just like VirtualBox default interface.)

"`1024*640`" * "`250%`" == "`2560*1600`"; (But guest machine "`Debian`"'s

resolution display do not have "`1024*640`".)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Win 10 VM on Linux host once into the Win 10 desktop.  The first line of @vittore's answer pointed me to what worked for me.  From VirtualBox settings (File > Preferences...) rather than any VM's settings:

[image: screenshot showing display preferences in virtualbox]

Change the settings in the "Display" section.  Either set the "Maximum Guest Screen Size" or the "Width" and "Height" as you see fit.  I chose to set the former to "Automatic".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but for others who are having the same issue. Can follow the following solution. This worked for me.

After the Ubuntu guest machine(In my case I am installing ubuntu virtual machine in windows) is installed, you will find the Ubuntu OS screen size is not extendable and you are not able to share folders between the host machine and Ubuntu.

For better screen resolution follow below steps.

**Step 1**

```
sudo adduser USERNAME sudo
```

where USERNAME should be replaced by the current user's name.

**Step 2**

```
To install Guest Additions, click Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD images…
```

**Step 3**

```
Click 'Run' button (next to 'Cancel' button) to start the installation. Note that the version of VBOXADDITIONS should be matched with the one of VirtualBox you have installed.
```

**Step 4**

```
Installing Guest Additions requires root privilege. Enter user's password (assume the current user has sudo privilege).
```

**Step 5**

```
When the installation is finished, press Return key to close the terminal window.
```

**Step 6**

```
Now prepare to restart the system to enable the change. Click 'Shutdown' on the menu and then the 'Restart' button.
```

After rebooting Ubuntu, you will see the desktop resolution is much better.

**For more clear Reference**

Check from Guest Addition(title) subsection in the below link. With clear images and explanation has done
https://brb.nci.nih.gov/seqtools/installUbuntu.html